# Why is this giving me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm creating a simply program to lookup a word in a dictionary.

Can you please tell me why this is creating a segmentation fault when the word is not found?

I've been staring at this for over an hour now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

bool equalStrings(const char s1[], const char s2[]);
int lookup(const struct entry dictionary[], const char search[], const int entries);

int main(void)
{
    const struct entry dictionary[100] =
        {{ "aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
         { "abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
         { "acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
         { "addle", "to become confused"},
         { "aerie", "a high nest"},
         { "affix", "to append; attach"},
         { "agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"},
         { "ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
         { "aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
         { "ajar", "partially opened"}};


    char word[10];
    int entries = 10;
    int entry;

    printf("Enter word: ");
    scanf("%14s", word);
    entry = lookup(dictionary, word, entries);

    if(entry != -1)
        printf("%s\n", dictionary[entry].definition);
    else
        printf("Sorry, the word %s is not in my dictionary\n", word);

    return 0;
}

bool equalStrings(const char s1[], const char s2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    bool areEqual;

    while(s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
        if(s1[i] == '\0' && s2[i] == '\0')
            areEqual = true;
        else
            areEqual = false;

    return areEqual;
}

int lookup(const struct entry dictionary[], const char search[], const int entries)
{
    int i;
    bool equalStrings(const char s1[], const char s2[]);

    for(i = 0; 1 < entries; i++)
    {
        if(equalStrings(search, dictionary[i].word))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }       
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: `1 < entries` typo. also `char word[10];` --> `char word[15];`

Comment: Why did you implement `equalStrings` yourself instead of using the common idiom `strcmp(s1, s2) == 0`?

Comment: Just learning the language via text book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; 1 < entries; i++)
```

`entries` is always `10` so the program will never end this loop, thus getting `i` out of bounds. Use `for(i = 0; i < entries; i++)` instead.